# Back to back single entry visa passport stamping

Tags: visas, schengen

What if I got two back to back Schengen visas, one from France (01-12 till 17-12) and the other from Finland (18-12 till 23-12), I would like to ask if my passport will be stamped as I got out from France and then when I'll reach Finland will be stamped for entering the Schengen area again, as I informed in the first visa application that I'll enter and get out from France so there should be an evidence that I left France according to the visa validity for not making any problems in the future as now I will enter the Schengen area from France and leave from Finland, however, I mentioned in each application I'll enter and leave the same country.

Answer (score 1):

You're passport is only stamped when entering and leaving the Schengen Area. If your flight from France to Finland is direct, you're passport will not be stamped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but is this problem in the future as now I will enter the Schengen area from France and leave from Finland, however, I mentioned in each application I'll enter and leave the same country.

Comment: @user67639 Please edit this extra point into the original question.